# How to store organized multiple belts?

Tags: clothing, organization

How can I store multiple belts in an organized way in my drawer/closet?

They're from different types/materials, and some different buckles.

I don't mind about the speed much, since usually I'm using the same 1-2 belts, and occasionally some of the others, but I do want to keep each one separately (i.e. not roll one over the other).

Currently they're just rolled in some piles, but the roll opens pretty fast or each time I have to move them a bit.

Most preferably without methods that suggests buying something to do it (a tool, holder, etc.).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I store mine:

[image: coiled belt]

As you can see, I just thread the tip of the belt through the buckle a few times. The buckle keeps the spiral in place. This arrangement makes for compact, tidy storage. You can see the belt design and the belt buckle. For multiple belts, as in your case, you can tip them on their "sides" (relative to what you see in the picture), and place them next to each other in rows in a drawer.

Comment: works great for most of my belts!

Comment: @arieljannai Happy to hear it!

Answer (score 3):

You can easily hang one belt on a regular clothes hanger.  Just thread the top of the clothes hanger through the belt buckle.  You can also hang your shirts/pants on the same hanger with the belt.

If you decide to buy something instead, there are many specialty hangers for hanging many belts on one hanger in the closet.  Search for "belt hanger" on Amazon for example.

Comment: A ["pants hanger"](https://images.homedepot-static.com/productImages/31caab01-f682-4a6c-8be9-e6baa47855a6/svn/chrome-black-honey-can-do-hangers-hngt01199-64_1000.jpg) (designed just like a regular hanger but without one of the diagonal sides) can hang multiple belts.

Comment: @BrettFromLA Yes. The pants hanger hack works well so long as the belts are pushed toward the "elbow" of the hanger so they don't slide off. This was the inspiration for my "S" hanger modification.

Answer (score 3):

Bend a wire into an "S" shape and hang your belts from it in the closet.
Side view.
[image]

Comment: You can also use the belt holes to hang your belts when the buckles aren't convenient for this. Also, "cinch" buckles usually have a hinge that can be used. You can add or remove from either side of this hanger for some kind of convenience. I made mine from a thick wire hanger. I have two for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

If your cloth cabinet is long, you can hang it via its belt metal. 
i think this is the best way to put your belt safe not to expire or be damaged.